# updating an arduino program by serial monitor when required

Tags: arduino, alter

I want to develop a product that connects with the wifi and uses web service for data logging. so the problem i am facing is that i want to update the program through serial monitor only and whenever required. for example if i entered my details of wifi and start using it then it should be saved in the program for further use and whenever i wanted to change my wifi i simply do it through serial monitor and reopening the whole program, updating it and loading it again. if anyone can provide a solution i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I really do not understand the question. Do you want to store WiFi settings like the SSID or the password of the router you are connecting to inside a non volatile memory? In this case you do not need to modify the program (code) but store the settings on an EEPROM http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything

Comment: thanks it helped me but i did used the sd card for storing the ssid and password which can be updated by the user anytime.